# HG: Checkout 'tipmost' tag

Tags: mercurial, tags

In mercurial, is there an easy way to programmatically check out the 'latest' tag?

Meaning, if `hg tags` produces this:

```
tip
Tag3
Tag2
Tag1
```

Is there an easy way to checkout Tag 3 in a generic way? Meaning, not just `hg checkout Tag3`, but a generic way of doing so.

EDIT: If I must use scripting, I can. However, I'm stuck on windows and would like to avoid scripting if possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it with [revsets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets).  Probably something like this:

```
hg update -r 'max(tagged())'
```

Comment: This is perfect! Cheers to you for knowing this. Side note: Couldn't get it to work on windows unless I used double quotes (") instead.

Comment: Works great! Tho from the revsets doc, seems `tagged()` isn't documented and `tag()` does the same.

Comment: Btw, to anyone who curious, I'm using this command in Jenkins mercurial plugin to pull only latest tagged release.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using bash:

```
hg checkout $(hg tags | sed -n '2p')
```

Note that this degrades gracefully: if there are no tags the subcommand will return blank and you'll get a simple checkout of the tip.

Comment: Haha.  Thanks for the +1.  For Windows you might write a little python script that will do this.  Mercurial has an internal Python API that's pretty straightforward, so you could call it instead of resorting to os.SubProcess() to run the tags and checkout.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a base hg command for this.  Good luck!

Comment: However, this will not give you the tipmost tag, merely the one which happens to have been added last (which is the same most of the time, but not always).